# subset a data frame using dplyr in R

Tags: r, dplyr

using R I'm trying to filter my data frame according to some arguments.

Here is the data frame:

```
Groups_name  col1   col2
group1       3       4
group1       1       1
group1       1       1
group2       1       1
group3       3       7
group3       1       1
group4       3       3
group4       1       1
```

and by group I want to only keep groups that contain at least one row where the `col1 > 1` and where `col1 == col2` or `col1 == col2+-2`

Here I should get:

```
Groups_name  col1   col2
group1       3      4
group1       1      1
group1       1      1
group4       3      3
group4       1      1
```

as you can see I kept the `group1` because the in the first row, the `col1 >1` and `col1 (3) = col2 +1 (4)` 
I also keep `group 3` because the `col1 >1` and `col1 (3) == col2  (3)`

but `group 1` was removed because the `col1` what `not > 1`

And I also removed the `group 3` because even if `col1 (3) > 1`, the `col1 (3)` is not equal to `7 +` or `- 2` (so not equal to `5,6,7,8` or `9`)

From now I tried:

```
tab %>%
  group_by(Groups_name) %>%
  filter(all(col1 == col2,col2-2,col2+2))  %>%
  filter(any(col1 > 1))
```

Thank for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `any` and `all` in the following way

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(Groups_name) %>%
  filter(any(col1 > 1) & all(abs(col1 - col2) %in% 0:2))

#  Groups_name  col1  col2
#  <fct>       <int> <int>
#1 group1          3     4
#2 group1          1     1
#3 group1          1     1
#4 group4          3     3
#5 group4          1     1
```

This selects groups where there is at least one value in `col1` greater than 1 and absolute difference between `col1` and `col2` is always between 0 and 2.

Answer (score 1):

We can do this in `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[any(col1 >1) & all(abs(col1 - col2) %in% 0:2)], .(Groups_name)]
#   Groups_name col1 col2
#1:      group1    3    4
#2:      group1    1    1
#3:      group1    1    1
#4:      group4    3    3
#5:      group4    1    1
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Groups_name = c("group1", "group1", "group1", 
"group2", "group3", "group3", "group4", "group4"), col1 = c(3L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L), col2 = c(4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 
3L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```